# Why is looking up an array value at a given index O(n) time complexity

Tags: arrays, data-structures, time-complexity, big-o

I have read that to look up the value at index n of an array, the computer will calculate (array start location) + (n * (data type size)) to find the location in memory of the value. Would this not take more than O(1) time because multiplication takes more than O(1) time?

Comment: Lookups in an array are generally O(1), not O(n).

Comment: Yes, that’s correct. Where did you hear that array lookups take time O(n)? That seems wrong to me, or perhaps a misinterpretation of another time bound?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, you are right in your thinking. Addition and multiplication can never be done in constant-time with respect to the input numbers.

The reason why indexed access is considered *O(1)* is that in practice, you work on a computer with limited RAM memory and an even more limited (logarithmic) address space. Indeed, these addresses usually fit in a single [word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)) on the hardware. They are considered constant-space in the context of [random-access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_access) memory. Thus, also simple arithmetic with these addresses are considered to run in constant-time. So anything you would do in practice on your machine, any algorithm you program, random-access can be assumed to be constant-time.

Basically, you compute *c + d * e* where all values are bounded by a constant.

But yes, if you consider a theoretical machine with infinite memory, then doing operations on your addresses will not be constant-time, even with random access.